# query to get n characters of string from the database table field with php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

//---query to get n characters of string from the database table field  with php codeigniter

//--view page

```
<?php  foreach ($query as $row)

{ 

$content = $row->blogger_content;

?>

<p> <?php echo $content; ?>

(here i want to list the content but only needed first 25 character) </p>

<?php  }  ?>

// what query want to use here..?
```

Comment: take your pick [substr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) or [substr](http://php.net/substr)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your model class.

```
$this->db->select(SUBSTRING(columnName, 0, 25))
         ->from(tablename)
         ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this and add second parameter FALSE, like:

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(columnName, 0, 25)', FALSE)
        ->from('table_name');
```

Setting second parameter to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use utf-8 character language - multi-byte - you have to use [**mb_substr**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead of `substr`

Comment: @semsem my $content bd field name is blog_content  and type is longtext and collation is latin1_swedish_c

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

into this

```
<?php echo strlen($content) > 25 ? substr($content, 0, 25).'...' : $content; ?>
```

that will check if the $content has more than 25 chars and display only 25 chars with ... at the end or else it will just display $content if not more than 25 chars

Comment: ....how ....  <?php echo count($content) > 25 ? substr($content, 0, 25).'...' : $content; ?>

Comment: that is a ternary operator. its just like an if else [http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4]

Comment: what error do you get? I just tested it and got a correct result

Comment: sorry... change the count to strlen

Comment: @ kenken  ok..this can only fetch and display one of my data in database table..if my $content is a group of data from the table then how can i change this query  as i want..please help me so figure it out..

Comment: you mean if the $content is an array? you should use foreach on that `foreach($content as $c){ $data1 = $c['data1']; $data2 = $c['data2']; $excerpt1 = count($data1) > 25 ? substr($data1, 0, 25).'...' : $data1; $excerpt2 = count($data2) > 25 ? substr($data2, 0, 25).'...' : $data2; }`

Answer (score 0):

Check `word_limiter` and `character_limiter` functions in [text helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/text_helper.html), so:

```
$content = character_limiter($row->blogger_content, 25);
```

That would be CodeIgniter way. Don't forget to autoload or load text helper.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$content_overview = (strlen($content) > 25) ? substr($content,0,25).'... <a href="#">Read More</a>' : $content;

echo $content_overview;

?>
```